# Fetching the user's current location

Tags: ios, objective-c, cllocation

There is a function that determines the user's location:

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
    didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation
           fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation{
    NSLog(@"Latitude = %f", newLocation.coordinate.latitude);
    NSLog(@"Longitude = %f", newLocation.coordinate.longitude);
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
       didFailWithError:(NSError *)error{
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    if ([CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled]){
        self.myLocationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
        self.myLocationManager.delegate = self;
        [self.myLocationManager startUpdatingLocation];
```

and there is such a function that considers the distance between two points

```
CLLocation *location1 = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:59.957069 longitude:30.323013];
CLLocation *location2 = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:60.050043 longitude:30.345783];

float betweenDistance = [location1 distanceFromLocation:location2];

NSLog(@"Distance is %f km", betweenDistance/1000);
```

I would like `location2` to be the user's current location. How do I determine that?

Comment: Your question is very confusing. Is the actual question is "is there a built-in driving directions calculator?" The answer to that is MapKit. See `MKDirectionsRequest`. Otherwise, please reword your question.

Comment: @Rob Napier i update the question

Comment: please check my edits to your question to make sure it is what you meant

Comment: @RobNapier  Yes, that's right

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully i understand you correctly, but to calculate the distance between 2 `CLLocations` just use the built in [distance method](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocation_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/CLLocation/distanceFromLocation:):

```
- (CLLocationDistance)distanceFromLocation:(const CLLocation *)location
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a property as `@property (nonatomic,strong) CLLocation *userLocation;`
and update this inside `didUpdateToLocation` method as `userLocation = newLocation`.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I'm new in objective-c, could you write much more insert method that he started to work

Comment: From the beginning, my goal - to find the user on the map and show the distance between the user and delivered my marker. As in this picture i.stack.imgur.com/Vjg9R.jpg The first is the name of the marker, and then the distance to it

Answer (score 0):

During `locationManager:didUpdateToLocation:`, you will be sent the user's current location. You need to store that in a property. After that, you can use that property to determine the user's location.

There is no synchronous call that will fetch the current location. You have to wait for it to come in from the location manager, and it may never come for many reasons (you may not have permission to access this information, or the GPS may be off, or many other reasons). Your code must be able to deal with this, and adjust itself when the data arrives.